# Attach a file (from s3) to a mail

Tags: php, laravel

This is what I am trying to do (using laravel-medialibrary):

```
        $message = Message::find(50);
        $media = $message->getFirstMedia();

        //todo can be more than one
        $fileName = $media->id . '/' . $media->file_name;

        $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($fileName);

        //create mailable

        $mail =  (new NotificationMail($this->template, new NotificationLog()))
            ->mailer('smtp')
            ->from('test@fdsf.co.uk', 'A. Test')
            ->subject('Any Luck')
            ->attach($file);
            

        $response =  Mail::to('fsdafd@gfdsg.com')->send($mail);
```

Tried to do this in various ways but the attachment is always just text in the mail:

```
--_=_swift_1601042677_ccb98caa4058cf66bc6face36e70ef0a_=_ Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="=?utf-8?Q?
```

Comment: Maybe you can try `->attachFromStorageDisk('s3', '/path/to/file');` with file path.

Comment: I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This was nonsense.

attachFromStorage was working but the mail was getting formatted after.

This was somehow setting the body empty which prevented the attachment from working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 $mail =  (new NotificationMail($this->template, new NotificationLog()))
                ->mailer('smtp')
                ->from('test@fdsf.co.uk', 'A. Test')
                ->subject('Any Luck')
                ->attachFromStorage('/path/to/file', 'name.pdf', ['mime' => 'application/pdf']);
```

or you can attach a path to email

```
$file = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fileName);
```

Comment: That didn't find the file, so I did ```->attachFromStorageDisk('s3', '39/', 'inboundNexmo.png', ['mime' => 'image/png']);``` and still get the same result.

Comment: Maybe you can try like this   @Mick  $mail->attachData($file, 'file_name.pdf');